# Update UpdatePanel from code behind on System.timers.timer elapsed event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, updatepanel

Is it possible, using asp.net and vb.net as the code behind, to update an UpdatePanel on a System.Timers.Timer elapsed event? I know a timer control is available, but please help me to do this with the Systems.Timer.Timer - I have reason to use it this way.

Every time the subroutine that handles my timer's elapsed event is called, I have a literal whose text I update. After I update the text, I call update() on my UpdatePanel. Nothing happens. I know there are ways to do this with Javascript on the client side, but if at all possible I want to stay away from that and stay server side, which I feel is what the Ajax UpdatePanel is trying to do for me anyway. I feel like the UpdatePanel should do exactly what I need, updating just a small portion of my page, in this case where my literal is stored. Thank you so much in advance.

Here is part of my markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="timerLit" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is my vb:

```
Protected Sub onTimerElapsed(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    timerLit.Text = "Hello"
    UpdatePanel1.update()
End Sub
```

I have tried many things. I know that my onTimerElapsed subroutine is called, and I know that the literal gets filled with the correct text. The update() just doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UpdatePanel only works from client to server. The scenario you are describing is not possible (at least not with the techniques you're using). That is because there's really no way for the server to connect to the client.

There are two possibilities:

- Either do it from client to server (which you discarded)
- Use a framework like SignalR if you really want to push it from the server-side.

SignalR implements the client-side and server-side plumbing for you and uses the best technique available in the current browser.

Here you can find more information on SignalR: http://signalr.net/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this clears things up. Now how exactly would I go from client to server and still use my elapsed event subroutine from my System.Timers.Timer? Is that possible?

Comment: No, you would need to do that on the client with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to go Server -> Client go from Client -> Server.

So in javascript create a timer that will call your code-behind every XXX seconds.

Something like this.

```
var myTimer = setInterval(myMethod, 5000);

function myMethod( )
{
  //this will repeat every 5 seconds
  //you can reset counter here
}
```

you can clear the timer and stop it calling your method by calling

```
clearInterval(myTimer);
```